# Multiple storage buckets after deploying only one - Google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

After deploying from my local development server to the app engine i suddenly have 2 other buckets created. Command for reference:

```
gloud app deploy
```

Everytime i delete them they pop back up as soon as i deploy again. The three buckets i have AFTER deploying are the following:

```
eu.artifacts.{app-id}.appspot.com
{app-id}.appspot.com
staging.{app-id}.appspot.com
```

Accessing all urls returns the same page. The first bucket contains a container with application images. The middle one contains nothing and the last one contains a folder named "appengine". Deleting them removes the ability to access them through the browser.

My questions: Why are they there? I dont want 3 urls with the same app and nowhere have i ever asked for them to be made.

It bugs me that they can be accessed through the browser when only the middle bucket is linked to an actual page.

Also it seems kinda dumb to have a "staging" area just containing and image of the actual live version. I mean it's already deployed..

Do anyone have a solution prevent these from being made or a solution in which they can't be accessed?

Close to this unanswered question:
[Bucket of Staging files after deploying an app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947918/bucket-of-staging-files-after-deploying-an-app-engine)

Answer (score 3):

These buckets get created automagically when deploying a new app. The default bucket, `{app-id}.appspot.com` has a 5GB free storage quota and is provided for your usage.

The staging bucket gets created when a default bucket gets created. It's lightly touched upon [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket), and take the following part into account:

> **Note:** When you create a default bucket, you also get a staging bucket
>   with the same name except that staging. is prepended to it. You can
>   use this staging bucket for temporary files used for staging and test
>   purposes; it also has a 5 GB limit, but ***it is automatically emptied on
>   a weekly basis.***

The 3rd one, `{region}.artifacts.{app-id}.appspot.com` is needed to actually build the docker container that GAE Flexible deploys. The [Container Builder Service](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/) is the one that actually does this, as indicated in the [GAE Flex docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_your_application)

The 3rd one is recreated on deployment of a new version, if you've deleted this bucket in the past. Deleting this bucket will *likely* increase your deploy times as the new deployment cannot build on your previous deployment.

Comment: Yeah but is there any way to removing web access to these buckets? I don't care that they exist, i just don't want 4 webpages with the exact same app

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: {region}.artifacts.{project-id}.appspot.com is defaulting to us multi región for me after deploying firebase or gcp functions. Multi región buckets are not part of the free plan. I'm trying to ser the bucket manually bit don't know how.

Comment: It's not possible to change it into regional, as the `build` bucket is created by default, however it's possible to delete the whole bucket to avoid charges, I suggest you to create a new question regarding this, since it seems that the [changes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes#August_05_2020) on how cloud functions are impacting the free tier