# Why Firebase Artifacts increases both the use of Storage and how to decrease?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Until 08/24 my storage day had only 19MB stored, for 1 user this was great, however, on 08/25 the use of Storage jumped to 460MB + - simply when this bucket of artifcats appeared, I don't even know what it is and because it consumes so much of my bank, what to do to reduce these surprise impacts and what exactly is this artifacts and their need?

Below I leave some images to simplify.
[image: Demonstration 1]

[image: Demonstratio 2]

Comment: Cloud Storage is used by other Firebase and Google Cloud products.  Since you aren't really saying what your project is doing, it's hard to explain for sure. If you have questions about billing, I suggest contacting Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Most likely these come from a change in how Cloud Functions builds its runtimes. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts/63580047#63580047

Comment: The changes of i made was exactly update Node JS from 8 to 10 and the size data appears

Comment: Similar response to @FrankvanPuffelen's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644106/why-is-my-firebase-storage-taken-up-by-region-artifacts-project-id-appspot-c