# Why is my Firebase storage taken up by [REGION].artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am currently using Firebase for a project. Under the storage section of my app, I noticed that I am storing approximately 500 MB (with a similar amount of MB sent for Bandwidth).

Nearly all of this comes from "[REGION].artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com" when I break it down, and I do not understand what this is. What is this, and do I have to worry about it taking up significantly more space in the future?

For context, I have zero files stored under storage, and hosting is storing less than 1 MB in total. I am using the Blaze plan so that I can deploy Node.js 10 cloud functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out the answer to my own question!

I believe this is related to the [Firebase's Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry), which is currently in Beta and is "a single place for your organization to manage container images and language packages (such as Maven and npm)."

This means that there is no need to worry about the used storage space growing significantly without any cause or warning, as the storage appears to be just for container images and language packages, not the hosting or function files themselves.

Comment: Do you have sure that the size is not increasing with time? In 3 days my data was of 450MB and now is 478MB...

Comment: @lukecross Originally I had thought it would not greatly increase, but mine has roughly doubled since I posted this question. This thread may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937542/can-i-delete-container-images-from-google-cloud-storage-artifacts-bucket

Comment: I deleted the Bucket but i'm fear that he comeback still bad more than before.