# Firebase storage is being filled and I don't know why

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I've found me Firebase's storage being using 1.3GB but when I check there are two files. One image I've uploaded (25Kb) and one I generated with cloud functions (38.63KB).

Then I went to Storage Usage and the graphic shows that 1.3GB is being used by **us.artifacts.<myapp>.appspot.com**

Digging around I've found in *https://console.cloud.google.com* under *us.artifacts.<myapp>.appspot.com* and inside of that I see a "containers/images" folder that contains

[image: images content]

and inside of "uploads"

[image: uploads content]

Checking the sizes, they don't add up to 1.3GB so I don't know where the rest of the files are.

I already set a policy to clear the storage, but I'd like to know where are these files coming from, and what they are.

Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: If you are using Cloud Functions, these are likely the build artifacts from that. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts

Comment: Let me refer to what Luke said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts#comment112618723_63580047) Also, am I doing something wrong here? because I don't understand how 16KB of functions needs 1.3GB of storage.

Comment: Containers take *much* more space than the simple code that runs in them, because they contain not just your code, but also its dependencies, the runtime that it runs on, and the operating system. I haven't looked at them myself yet, but assume you can probably inspect the files to see where the bulk of their size comes from to see if you can optimize that. Doing so will not just save storage space, but will typically also improve cold start times.

Comment: Thank you Frank!