# Not able to deploy cloud function - ensure registry read/write access to us.gcr.io

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy a simple cloud function **(gen1)** in my project. I have **owner** permission for the project.

however, while deploying I am getting following error.

```
"build": ERROR: failed to initialize analyzer: validating registry write access: ensure registry read/write access to us.gcr.io/project_xxx/gcf/northamerica-northeast1/3c5aeef8-dfbd-43de-9873-16a1b68e54ed/cache:4f2ca2a4-acef-42e1-94e2-3123fcd93c70"
```

I also provided **Artifact Registry Administrator** role to the service account tied to cloud function. however, I am still getting above error.

**Update 1:**

I gave **Artifact Registry Administrator** permission for cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com service account as well. However, same error.

[image]

**Update 2**

Just to isolate the problem, I gave owner permission to both the service accounts. cloud function and cloud build service account and I am still getting this issue.

I checked the path as well for artifactory and it's empty.
us.gcr.io/project-xxx/gcf/northamerica-northeast1/f4d0d3b2-6ed4-4e04-aab1-708b19e26d9c/cache:39767ec4-9f7d-4992-82c8-ae8d9658b909

I also, deleted the entire function and created new one with same service account and still getting issue.

**Update 3:**
I checked the cloudbuild settings and seems like it has all the access required.
[image]

Comment: Can you try to add the Artifact Registry Administrator role to the Cloud Build service agent? In addition, is it a new project? what the activated services? Do you use Cloud Functions gen1 or gen2?

Comment: it's a new project and gen1 cloud func. what should I look under activated services.

Comment: Do you have activated all these API? Cloud Functions, Cloud Build, Artifact Registry, Cloud Storage, Logging.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes all the API's are enabled.

Comment: This answer suggests that the issue lies with the images in the container registry and deleteing them and redeploying might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67373593/151759 An entry in the google cloud community suggests cloud debugger permission, but I do not see any connection to your problem. But maybe it is worth a try.

Comment: @Bertolt i gave owner permission to both the service account and deleted everything from storage bucket, registry was empty already and created new function and still the same error.

Comment: @GaurangShah, have you also tried [granting a role to the Cloud Build service account using the Settings page](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account#service-account-permissions-settings)?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting Artifact Registry permissions, but by default, gcr.io urls are handled by Container Registry. If you want to use gcr.io urls with Artifact Registry, you can run (needs roles/storage.admin):

`gcloud beta artifacts settings enable-upgrade-redirection --project=PROJECT_ID`

(See https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/setup-gcr-repo for more detailed info)

If you want to use Container Registry (not recommended), you should use these permissions: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control

Answer (score 0):

The answers given in this post didn't help me to resolve my case, so I share with you what worked for me.

I had the same issue and error message for the gen 1. Giving the libraries used in the code in the requirements.txt file resolved the problem.

For the gen 2, the error was "Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable." for the same configuration. Giving the libraries used in the code in the requirements.txt file worked too.