# Firebase Non-Firebase services costs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I am developing the mobile application with Flutter and Firebase.

Still on developing stage, I am going forward for publishing the app.

I had the issue with the Non-Firebase services costs.

It doesn't cost me this much before but suddenly I am getting high costs.

I tried to figure it out , but I couldn't find the reason..

Artifact Registry API = >. Could you tell me what is this ?

and I attached my usage list and the packages list.

Please let me know if you can find any of clue ....

Thanks for reading. I am waiting for your help.

[image]

[image]

```
     cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
      go_router: ^4.1.0
      cloud_firestore: ^3.3.0
      firebase_storage: ^10.3.4
      firebase_core: ^1.19.1
      flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
      # sign_in_with_apple: ^4.0.0
      firebase_auth: ^3.7.0
      flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.4
      google_sign_in: ^5.3.3  
      flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.3  
      firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1
      font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
      firebase_core_web: ^1.7.1
      google_sign_in_web: ^0.10.2
      timeago: ^3.2.2
      flutter_app_badger: ^1.4.0
      rich_text_controller: ^1.4.0
      flutter_calendar_carousel: ^2.4.0
      carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
      syncfusion_flutter_xlsio: ^20.2.46-beta
      fl_chart: ^0.55.1
      # flutter_html: ^2.2.1
      google_mobile_ads: ^2.3.0
      timelines: ^0.1.0
      range_slider_flutter: ^0.0.2
      like_button: ^2.0.5
      hive: ^2.2.3
      hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
      reorderable_grid: ^1.0.5
      calendar_view: ^1.0.1
      in_app_review: ^2.0.6
      flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
      timezone: ^0.9.1
      flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
      flutter_native_timezone: ^1.1.0
      lat_lng_to_timezone: ^0.2.0
      cloud_functions: ^3.3.8
      device_info_plus: ^8.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Artifact Registry is used by Google Cloud Functions to store the container images that it builds to host your code. Under the hood, Artifact Registry stores these images in Cloud Storage.

The Firebase CLI usually removes these containers after each build, but if some of them remain they may lead to charges for Cloud Storage. Also see the FAQ [Why do I need a billing account to use Cloud Functions for Firebase?](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#why-billing) that explains a bit more about this, and these previous questions:

- [Firebase storage artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts)
- [Firebase storage artifacts is huge and keeps increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843721/firebase-storage-artifacts-is-huge-and-keeps-increasing)
- And this [post on /r/Firebase on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/lj3tsy/why_am_i_being_charged_for_cloud_storage_when_it/)