# How Firebase calculates storage for fields? Fireabase storage reporting excessive usage

Tags: firebase

I have 8 Firebase user entries in Firebase Cloud Firestore (around 8 simple string fields in each), and two uploaded images, 200KB and 1.1MB, yet Firebase is reporting almost 1GB of storage? Also, what are artifacts?

Looks like this issue is a dupe of [Firebase storage artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts)

Leaving it open here...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no execessive usage here. Please bear in mind that Cloud Storage includes Firebase and Cloud products. If any Cloud buckets are being used by GCP resources, those would count here. go to the Storage usage as in your screenshot and check what's causing this storage usage by hovering with your mouse on the graph. it should show what's being used.

Comment: Thanks I did! Added a screenshot, but did not become more knowledgable. 81 something in us.artifacts. Whatever that is. I think Firebase will need some better accounting or I will switch to my own Mysql :P

Comment: Looks like there is a similar questoin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts