# Where are the costs of Compute Engine and Cloud Build in firebase (gcp?)?

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-platform

I made an app using firebase.

However, for three months, the costs shown in the picture below were incurred.

Where did Computer Engine and Cloud Build cost?

The suspected part of Computer Engine requires a static IP to use external services, but uses GCP's vpn network.

The suspect part of Cloud Build seems to occur when deploying cloud functions. Am I right? If there is a cost during deployment, why does depolying the whole with firebase deploy from the terminal incur more cost regardless of the modified part?

[35,488 == Services other than firebase]
Please help!

[image: in firebase console]

[image: in gcp console]

Comment: Most likely the storage cost is for storing the resulting container images that come our of Cloud Build, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts. But Stack Overflow is not a great place to answer billing questions, so I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a software development question as specified in the [help], but a customer services question for the vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the storage cost is for storing the resulting container images that come our of Cloud Build, as explained here: [Firebase storage artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts). But Stack Overflow is not a great place to answer billing questions, so I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.