# Google invoice charged fees for unused functions (settings problem?)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I received an invoice from Google and they charged 2 cents from my account because I had been using Cloud Storage module which (to my knowledge) I did not.

I assume there is a connection between some modules I've been using which lead to the problem. I will describe my setup, maybe someone can clarify:

I have a Firebase account containing two project (android, web). The plan is "blaze-as-you-go".

I have 1 Cloud Function that sends push notifications to subscribers via the Cloud Messaging module of Firebase. The function was called about 10 times in the last 7 days. The apps are in the developing process at the moment, there aren't any users yet.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the storage quota:

[image]

I don't know why 794 MB of storage are used. If I click on the card I get redirected from Firebase to the Google Cloud Console which tells me to create an app.

Can anyone give me a hint what the problem is and how I can fix it? I don't want to pay huge amounts just because I missed a settings switch or wrote bad code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use Cloud Functions, most likely you have an additional bucket in your project where Cloud Build put some temporary files when you ran `firebase deploy`. You can safely delete those, but unless you do they will indeed lead to a small charge. The latest CLI releases will clean up their own temp files once they deploy completes. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts

Comment: This is "good". I just was worried I'd ran into huge amounts of costs without knowing why but that won't happen now. Thanks :)