# Firebase still charge even though my Cloud Storage is empty

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

As you can see from the image attached below, I got 470MB that is still stored in my cloud storage.

[image: My firebase cloud storage usage]

I deleted all my files, images that I stored there so it should be free of spaces inside my firebase storage. But then, it still shows up 470MB is stored in my firebase storage.

[image: Cloud Storage Files (Empty)]

So, my concern is that even though I already deleted all the files, the usage is still showing that I still have 470MB in my storage. Because of it, Firebase charged me RM0.01 (Malaysian currency, about 0.00001USD) per month. I sticked with Blaze plan before but because of this, I revert back to spark plan.

Currently still testing and building the app, and its not big of a deal to pay RM0.01 per month but I'm afraid it will got me pay some amounts that I dont understand, going forward. Any advice or reason/explanation regarding this?

Comment: Got any rtdb or firestore docs?

Comment: Have you read about [Firebase storage artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578581/firebase-storage-artifacts)?